# Angular js loads in browser but not with selenium

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing javascript selenium webdriver tests to access a web page. The angular js elements load just fine when I access the page, but if I try to access the page from the selenium tests, the elements don't load. I've already checked to see that I've connected to the correct profile path. What could be causing this? The only error I see in the browser console is "Error: Permission denied to access property '0'", but I know that my account has the correct permissions.

Comment: For testing Angular JS applications, there is a tool called Protractor which is built on top of Selenium-webdriverjs. http://angular.github.io/protractor/

Comment: I'm already using protractor. It was working before, but I cannot figure out what changed for the life of me.

Comment: Have you set ignoresynchronisation property somewhere!!?? You probly need to provide some more info for sm1 to be able to help you..

Comment: I figured it out. My browser upgraded to an incompatible version of Firefox without my knowledge. That was the issue.

Comment: You can mark the question answered in this case!